# Acts-as-tree in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-tree

I need to use Acts As Tree in my Rails3 project (ruby 1.9.2). But, there are lot of forks on github, so I don't know which should I choose, and which is used by other developers?
On Railsplugins.org there are http://www.railsplugins.org/plugins/376-acts-as-tree, but last commit was from March...

Answer (score 6):

I'm using http://rubygems.org/gems/acts_as_tree_rails3.  Works great.

Answer (score 2):

I've gone with https://github.com/skyeagle/nested_set on my Rails3 projects. It's hard to say at this point where adoption will take things.

Comment: can you tell me how it turned?

Comment: awesome_nested_set is now Rails 3. That's what I would do now. https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/

Comment: This might help you decide, as well: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Nesting

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree if you can add a new table to store the hierarchies and want efficient select and mutate performance.