# Rails Duplex comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

I'm interested in the question of the two-level comments

for example: I use some `post` with `comments` list

The user can add his/her own comments, and in my app I show all comments like that:

```
<div id='com'>
    <%= render @post.comments %>
</div>
```

in my `view/comments/_comment`:

```
<div class='comments'>
    <p>
      <strong>Commenter:</strong>
      <%= comment.commenter %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Comment:</strong>
      <%= comment.body %>
    </p>
    <%= link_to "Del", [comment.post, comment], :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
    <hr>
</div>
```

in my `comments` table I have `post_id` and `body` of comment ( and other fields )
and my View, I `show` all comments to post by `created_at` (I not sure but I think this is right assumption ) because I use `<%= render @post.comments %>`

And that is question: I don't understand how can I realize two-level comments?

I am also looking for simple examples on this theme, please.
or tell me the main idea of this implementation...

UPD:

i create some post in my blog :
first user commented it, second user commented it, third user commented it

than i open post, saw three comments and i disagreed with first commenter - and i want put my comment between first commenter and second commenter - how can i realize that?

Comment: well so far i could get from your questions is, you are showing `comments` of a `post` by the order of its **creation date**. Then what did you really meant by **two level comments**? Do you think that you can rephrase your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Please follow the updated part first***

So you mean your `comments` can have a `comment` as parent. In the case you described, the `comment` from the **first user** is the `parent` of **your comment**. If I got it correctly, then the best suggestion is to use `acts_as_tree` plugin.
Your comments model should act like a tree. Try using this **https://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree**.

If you are using rails3 then **[Acts-as-tree in Rails3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580597/acts-as-tree-in-rails3)** might help. Let me know if you face any problem using the plugins.

**Update:**

Another googling gave me these links. **I think you need exactly this implementation**.

- http://kconrails.com/2010/10/23/nested-comments-in-ruby-on-rails-1-models/
- http://kconrails.com/2011/01/26/nested-comments-in-ruby-on-rails-controllers-and-views/